# Prisma get data based on computed field

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-binding

I need to get data depends on computed field
For example

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
      const fragment = `fragment EnsureFullName on User { firstName lastName }`
      return ctx.db.query.users({}, addFragmentToInfo(info, fragment))
    },
  },
  User: {
    fullName: parent => `${parent.firstName} ${parent.lastName}`,
  },
}
```

I need to get all data where fullname = 'any value',

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter manually after fetching from the database or use use a where condition to check if firstName and lastName:

```
const users = await prisma.users({ where: { firstName: 'any', lastName: 'value' } });
```